# Как очистить кэш событий для телеграмм бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, события, callback

Есть телеграмм бот, написанный на Python. Проблема заключается в том, что по какой-то причине если вырубить сервер, и потом два раза ввести /start, то при следующем запуске сервера бот будет присылать дубликаты на абсолютно любые запросы. Я так понимаю, что дело в том, что на сервере записываются события, которые копятся даже если отключить сервер. Вопрос состоит в следующем: можно ли как-то очистить эти события? Или сделать так, чтобы они не копились больше одного? Использую telebot

Comment: В `aiogram`, к примеру, есть параметр `skip_updates`, который при запуске бота игнорирует все сообщения, которые были отправлены ему, пока он находился в офлайне. Но на сколько мне известно в `telebot` такого нет